# Add view to another view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

So I have one view added from storyboad

```
@IBOutlet weak var jobListBackgroundView: UIView!
```

now in one function i want to add one view which has button and label in it programmatically.

```
func setUpcomingInterviewView(){
    var customview = UIView()
    customview.backgroundColor = UIColor.dashboardScreenHeader
    customview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 47)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 12, width:170, height: 18)
    titleLabel.text = headerSection[0]
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(16)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("See All", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.customBlueColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 303, y: 14, width: 62, height: 12)

    customview.addSubview(titleLabel)
    customview.addSubview(button)
    customview  = jobListBackgroundView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 47))
    self.view.addSubview(customview)

}
```

how should I implement this?

I haven't added a view programmatically before, so don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: I think you need to change `customview  = jobListBackgroundView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 47))
` to    `jobListBackgroundView = customview`

Comment: it's look ok, what's wrong with your code!

Comment: @SPatel he's adding `customview` as subview of `view`

Comment: @RobertDresler is not valid thing?

Comment: @SPatel I think he wants to add it as `jobListBackgroundView`'s subview

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
func setUpcomingInterviewView(){
    var customview = UIView()
    customview.backgroundColor = UIColor.dashboardScreenHeader
    customview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 47)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 12, width:170, height: 18)
    titleLabel.text = headerSection[0]
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(16)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("See All", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.customBlueColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 303, y: 14, width: 62, height: 12)

    customview.addSubview(titleLabel)
    customview.addSubview(button)

    self.jobListBackgroundView.addSubview(customview)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `customView` at all, just directly use `jobListBackgroundView` like so:

```
func setUpcomingInterviewView(){
    jobListBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.dashboardScreenHeader
    jobListBackgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 47)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 11, y: 12, width:170, height: 18)
    titleLabel.text = headerSection[0]
    titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.withSize(16)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("See All", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.customBlueColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 303, y: 14, width: 62, height: 12)

    jobListBackgroundView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    jobListBackgroundView.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: fair enough, removed the add to subview stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `customView` as subview of `jobListBackgroundView`

```
jobListBackgroundView.addSubview(customview)
```

---

```
func setUpcomingInterviewView(){
    ...
    customview.addSubview(titleLabel)
    customview.addSubview(button)
    jobListBackgroundView.addSubview(customview)
}
```

Comment: it's not displaying anything . using the above method in jobListBackgroundView

Comment: @ArinjaySharma in? What do you think? Maybe `jobListBackgroundView` doesn't have constraints set proparly